# How to submit one of many forms generated from loop by clicking on text

Tags: javascript

A query returns an array of notifications, which is looped through on the front-end. For each item in the array, I have two options: `Mark as read`, `Delete`, each is text. The objective is to trigger a form submission by clicking on the text.

The front end code that is being looped is a button with a drop-down with the selections. I want to be able to click the text to submit the form. The JavaScript I have learned is tricky. I have two ways to get a click response, but I am stuck because I cannot figure out how to submit the form.

```
<button class="btn btn-light btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <form action="/notifications/{{ $notification->id }}/edit" method="POST" name="updateNotificationForm" class="update-notification-form">
        @csrf
        {{-- @method('PUT') --}}
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $notification->id }}">
        <p class="update-notification pl10">Mark read</p>
    </form>
    <form action="/notifications/delete/{{ $notification->id }}" method="POST" class="delete-notification-form">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $notification->id }}">
        <p class="delete-notification pl10">Delete</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Screenshot of front-end***
[image]

Here's the Javascript:

**Method one:**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.update-notification').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
        console.log("Mark read clicked");

        // submit form
        
    });
});
```

**Method two:**

[JavaScript Resource](https://gomakethings.com/attaching-multiple-elements-to-a-single-event-listener-in-vanilla-js/)

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if ( event.target.classList.contains('update-notification') ) {
        console.log("Mark read was clicked");

        // submit form
   
    }
}, false);
```

The `console.log` shows that each method links to every element in the array, but I cannot figure out how to submit the form.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to simply target the parentNode of the target itself and trigger a submit.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.update-notification').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
        console.log("Mark read clicked");
         event.target.parentNode.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Bravo! Thanks so much! Your solution works for both methods! Excellent!